# How to calculate big-theta

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

Can some one provide me a real time example for how to calculate big theta.

Is big theta some thing like average case, (min-max)/2?

I mean (minimum time - big O)/2

Please correct me if I am wrong, thanks

Comment: Have you read e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation, which has a table comparing the various asymptotic notations?

Comment: thanks for the link, yes i gone through this before; the table mainly describes abt big O and am hard to follow that, however i need real time example to get more understanding

Answer (score 8):

Big-theta notation represents the following rule:

> For any two functions `f(n)`, `g(n)`, if `f(n)/g(n)` and `g(n)/f(n)` are both bounded as `n` grows to infinity, then `f = Θ(g)` and `g = Θ(f)`. In that case, `g` is both an upper bound and a lower bound on the growth of `f`.

Here's an example algorithm:

```
def find-minimum(List) 
  min = +∞
  foreach value in List 
    min = value if min > value
  return min
```

We wish to evaluate the cost function `c(n)` where `n` is the size of the input list. This algorithm will perform one comparison for every item in the list, so  `c(n) = n`.

`c(n)/n = 1` which remains bounded as  `n` goes to infinity, so `c(n)` grows no faster than `n`. This is what is meant by big-O notation `c(n) = O(n)`. Conversely, `n/C(n) = 1` also remains bounded, so `c(n)` grows no slower than `n`. Since it grows neither slower nor faster, it must grow at the same speed. This is what is meant by theta notation `c(n) = Θ(n)`.

Note that `c(n)/n²` is also bounded, so `c(n) = O(n²)` as well — big-O notation is merely an upper bound on the complexity, so any `O(n)` function is *also* `O(n²)`, `O(n³)`...

However, since `n²/c(n) = n` is not bounded, then `c(n) ≠ Θ(n²)`. This is the interesting property of big-theta notation: it's both an upper bound *and* a lower bound on the complexity.

Comment: As I know that's not a big theta definition, there isn't anything says F(n)/G(n) it just says f(n) <= C1 g(n) and g(n) <= C2 f(n) ...., for your definition counter example, assume f = g = 0 for all n, so your definition has no meaning for this sample.

Comment: Both definitions are equivalent, except for f = g = 0.

Comment: For the example algorithm above: Should min be initially negative infinity? And only be set if min < value ?

Answer (score 1):

Big theta is a tight bound, for a function `T(n)`: if: `Omega(f(n))<=T(n)<=O(f(n))`, then Theta(f(n)) is the tight bound for T(n).

In other words Theta(f(n)) 'describes' a function T(n), if both O [big O] and Omega, 'describe' the same T, with the same f.

for example, a quicksort [with correct median choices], always takes at most O(nlogn), at at least Omega(nlogn), so quicksort [with good median choices] is Theta(nlogn)

**EDIT:**
added discussion in comments:

Searching an array is still Theta(n). the Theta function does not indicate worst/best case, but the behavior of the desired case. i.e, searching for an array, T(n)=number of ops for worst case. in here, obviously `T(n)<=O(n)`, but also `T(n)>=n/2`, because at worst case you need to iterate the whole array, so `T(n)>=Omega(n)` and therefore Theta(n) is asymptotic bound.

Comment: How about a searching a array of length n,

here the best case is O(1) and worst case is O(n), then what is big theta in this case

Comment: @Navin Leon: it is still Theta(n) worst case, the behavior of the Theta function is not worst/best case, it's asymptotic bound for the case you are looking for. i.e, searching for an array, T(n)=number of ops for worst case. in here, obviously `T(n)<=O(n)`, but also `T(n)>=n/2`, because at worst case you need to iterate the whole array, so `T(n)>=Omega(n)` and therefore Theta(n) is asymptotic bound.

Answer (score 0):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations, we learn that "Big O" denotes an upper bound, whereas "Big Theta" denotes an upper and lower bound, i.e. in the limit as `n` goes to infinity:

```
f(n) = O(g(n))      -->    |f(n)| < k.g(n)

f(n) = Theta(g(n))  -->    k1.g(n) < f(n) < k2.g(n)
```

So you cannot infer Big Theta from Big O.

Comment: How about a searching a array of length n,

here the best case is O(1) and worst case is O(n), then what is big theta in this case

Comment: @Navin: Big-O, etc., are not about best or worst case.

Answer (score 0):

ig-Theta (Θ) notation provides an asymptotic upper and lower bound on the growth rate of an algorithm's running time. To calculate the big-Theta notation of a function, you need to find two non-negative functions, f(n) and g(n), such that:

There exist positive constants c1, c2 and n0 such that 0 <= c1 * g(n) <= f(n) <= c2 * g(n) for all n >= n0.
f(n) and g(n) have the same asymptotic growth rate.
The big-Theta notation for the function f(n) is then written as Θ(g(n)). The purpose of this notation is to provide a rough estimate of the running time, ignoring lower order terms and constant factors.

For example, consider the function f(n) = 2n^2 + 3n + 1. To calculate its big-Theta notation, we can choose g(n) = n^2. Then, we can find c1 and c2 such that 0 <= c1 * n^2 <= 2n^2 + 3n + 1 <= c2 * n^2 for all n >= n0. For example, c1 = 1/2 and c2 = 2. So, f(n) = Θ(n^2).